# Связать 2 массива

Tags: php

Здравствуйте, уже пол дня ломаю голову, все не могу связать 2 массива родителя и ребенка. есть массивы

**Parent**

```
  [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 15
            [title] => Название
        )
```

**Child**

```
  [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [parent] => 15
        )

  [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 2
            [parent] => 15
        )
```

Как к массиву $parent добавить ключ [child] с содержимым массива $child, с учетом того что $parent['id'] должен быть равен $child['parent']

Из данного примера получиться должно так

```
     [0] => Array
            (
                [id] => 15
                [title] => Название
                [child] => Array (
                        [0] => Array
                                (
                                    [id] => 1
                                    [parent] => 15
                                )

                        [1] => Array
                            (
                                [id] => 2
                                [parent] => 15
                            ) 
                        )

            )
```

Comment: Я не очень понял, что должно получиться в итоге :) Можно пример, прямо на данных из вопроса?

Comment: тебе нужно в структуре (т.е. изначально задать так) или программно (чтобы после выполнения кода из 2 массивов получился необходимый массив)?

Comment: Добавил : )

Comment: а чем не годится $parent[0]['child']=$child ?

Comment: @eicto, используя $parent[0]['child']=$child вы не гарантируете того, что в child родителя будут добавлены только те элементы, родителем которых является данный элемент.

К тому же - если надо будет реализовать эту схему для нескольких родителей? Ведь parent указан как массив, а значит кроме первого элемента может быть и второй.

Comment: в смысле не гарантирую? я это декларирую такой конструкцией. а понял, исходный должен называться $children, и задача установить дерево детей-родителей... рекурсия

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
foreach ($parent as &$parentElement) {
    $parentElement['child'] = array();
    foreach ($child as &$childElement) {
        if ($childElement['parent'] != $parentElement['id']) {
            continue;
        }
        $parentElement['child'][] = $childElement;
    }
}
```

Задачу решает, хотя мне здесь не нравится то, что массив child гоняем туда-обратно.

Можно по-другому поступить:

```
$result = array();
foreach ($parent as &$parentElement) {
    $parentId = $parentElement['id'];
    $result["$parentId"] = array(
        'parent' => $parentElement,
        'child' => array(),
    );
}
foreach ($child as &$childElement) {
    $parentId = $childElement['parent'];
    if (!isset($result["$parentId"])) {
        continue;
    }
    $result["$parentId"]['child'][] = $childElement;
}
```

Таким образом получаем массив, состоящий из набора элементов (parent и массив child). Пользоваться им не так удобно, зато проходов при построении совершаем куда меньше.

Если будет надо - можно из последнего примера получить исходный массив. Но это опять же - лишние телодвижения.

И еще - цель была построить ассоциативный массив, поэтому использую в ключах "$parentId". Сработает или нет - не знаю, проверять лень, хотя по идее должно отработать нормально, не как с числами.

Comment: Ваш второй вариант работает верно, за исключением того что создает ключ Child на уровень выше, а должен ключ Child создаваться рядом с id,title посмотрите пожалуйста мой пост, там исходная картина которая должна получиться.

Comment: Изменил предпоследнюю стройку на   
$result["$parentId"]['products_id']['child'][] = $childElement;  
Большое спасибо.

Comment: Так в том и суть - во втором варианте создается не совсем тот массив, который нужен, но создается он (при больших размерах исходных массивов) гораздо быстрее, чем в первом варианте.

Товарищ @ReinRaus, кстати, немного опередил меня в этом. Его вариант и мой первый вариант - по сути есть одно и то же. Разница в том, что я использую указатели.

Преобразовать мой второй вариант к нужному вам виду легко:

    $newResult = array();
    foreach ($result as $values) {
        $parent = $values['parent'];
        $parent['child'] = $values['child']
        $newResult[] = $parent;
    }

Comment: Но мне в этом не нравится то, что опять проходимся по циклу. Если элементов будет мало - лишние траты времени. Лучше использовать первый вариант.

Либо переделать немного логику - можно создать два метода - getParent и getChild, и при проходе в цикле по полученному во втором варианте массиву вызывать их. Этот вариант кажется более правильным. Не зацикливаешься на названии ключей.

Answer (score 1):

```
$parent['child']=Array();
foreach ($child as $k=>$v) 
    if ($v['parent']==$parent['id'])
        $parent['child'][]=$v;
```

Comment: А можно полную версию? ведь вашу конструкцию нужно обвернуть в цикл, ибо откуда брать $parent['id'] ?

Comment: Я думал Вам нужен алгоритм, а оказалось нужен сниппет. Простите.

Comment: Если выбирать между алгоритмом и сниппетом конечно же я выберу сниппет, на работе время не ждет :) Вот был бы я дома.. Еще вернусь к вашим строчкам алгоритма : )